# AMPPS for Mac, local vhosts now no longer working

Tags: apache, macos-catalina, ampps

AMPPS 3.9 64-bit for Mac is working fine on MacOS 10.15.2.

I created some .local vhosts in `/Applications/Ampps/Apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`, and added the domains to /etc/hosts.

All was running well, I had about 5 different .local vhosts up and running fine.

On 1 .local website, after running WP Migrate DB Pro pulling a remote db down into the local site, every .local vhost has failed to load, producing `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Restarting Apache has not resolved the issue.

I've double checked `/etc/hosts/` & `httpd-vhosts.conf` and they both look fine.

I've tried `Restore Config` in the AMPPS control panel with no success. Rebooted with no success.

http://localhost/phpmyadmin opens fine.

Help and troubleshooting advice appreciated.

Comment: How large was your db table when you did the migration?

Comment: Which version of `WP Migrate DB Pro` did you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the local IP address had changed somehow, after running WP Migrate DB Pro.

Updating the hosts file with the new IP address has fixed the problem.